Error: release: not found when trying to rollback existing helm release
I am currently running into an issue where when I try to rollback a helm release (that exists) I am getting an error saying the release cannot be found.
When I run helm rollback johndoe-anon-app 1, I keep getting the error Error: release: not found, but I expect to be able to rollback the release as normal.
When I try the command helm list I get the following output which contradicts the above error:
NAME                NAMESPACE                           REVISION    UPDATED                                 STATUS      CHART       APP VERSION
johndoe-anon-app    service-johndoe-anon-dev    12          2024-04-30 06:26:05.708824 +1000 AEST   deployed    app-1.12.0             



When I run helm history johndoe-anon-app I also get the following output:
REVISION    UPDATED                     STATUS      CHART       APP VERSION DESCRIPTION     
11          Tue Apr 30 06:25:00 2024    superseded  app-1.12.0              Upgrade complete
12          Tue Apr 30 06:26:05 2024    deployed    app-1.12.0              Upgrade complete

I have already run the command kubectl config set-context --current --namespace=service-johndoe-anon-dev so I don't think this is a namespace issue. Does anyone have recommendations for further avenues for troubleshooting?

Thank you for your question. Questions focused specifically on Kubernetes, such as configuring or deploying a cluster, may be better answered by the experts in either the [sf] or DevOps. These platforms are highly knowledgeable in Kubernetes and can provide comprehensive support tailored to your needs. As a reminder, all questions on Stack Overflow must be specifically related to programming. We appreciate your understanding and encourage you to visit the "on-topic" pages of either site before posting there to ensure a more relevant and helpful response.

What do you see when you run helm history johndoe-anon-app?

@Vahid I have edited the question with the output

Do you provide the namespace when you run the helm rollback command?

Even when I do include the namespace I get the same result (though I shouldn't need to set the namespace since I already ran kubectl config set-context --current --namespace=service-johndoe-anon-dev)

Assuming you are in the correcgt namespace. For revision number you are passing 1 but when you run helm history johndoe-anon-app you see 11 and 12. Can you use one of these number and see how it behaves
